# Should commas be used in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> Various kinds of meat and fish in the bazaar were found by the cook.

In the sentence, should commas be used before and after the phrase 'in the bazaar'? If commas is used there, the phrase is an adverb. If not, it is an adjective, I think.

Comment: Who wrote this, Yoda?  Far more natural to say "Various kinds of meat and fish were found by the cook in the bazaar"

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence as it stands is fine without commas

> Various kinds of meat and fish in the bazaar were found by the cook.

If you insisted on using commas, you might write

> In the bazaar, various kinds of meat and fish were found by the cook.
>   The cook found, in the bazaar, various kinds of meat and fish.

Answer (score -1):

The sentence of yours is correct and no comma is required.
However, if you really want to add a comma then your sentence could be written in this way,

> Various kinds of meat, and fish in the bazaar were found by the cook.

Other than this, there's no possible place in the sentence where you can add a comma.

Comment: This use of a comma is not correct.